# implementation of extra security login for SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

For one banking enterprise there is a separate SharePoint 2010 sales portal. Now company wants to implement extra layer of security by providing another extra login for all contributor to the sales site. Even a AD user has to pass through login for that particular application. How to implement extra login for AD user in SharePoint 2010?

problem is already all users are authenticated by SharePoint application. On top of that we want to implement another authentication/ login

Comment: Try looking into Forms Based Authentican (FBA) login.

Comment: problem is already all users are authenticated by SharePoint application. On top of that we want to implement another authentication/ login. I have doubt if it is possible through FBA...

Answer (score 0):

Two factor authentication for SharePoint can easily be achieved using Microsoft UAG (Unified Access Gateway).

Comment: in that case Forms Based Authentican (FBA) is not possible? Plz clarify. is MS UAG only option?

Comment: You could do it with ADFS as well

Comment: Still it is not clear if FBA is possible on top of classic authentication or not?  Wictor Wilen has suggested 2 way 1. MS UAG & 2. ADFS . I am not sure which one is correct? need more discussion on this?

Comment: There's no correct way, you have multiple options. If you use UAG for instance then the end-users can use a Web Form to enter username and password and optionally a second token or similar. This will then be sent to SharePoint doing "real" Windows AuthN.

Comment: Hi wictor, some experts said that this is highly possible simply through FBA. UAG is unnecessary in this case. What is your say in this case? Plz check http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/29c06690-f786-4189-81a0-1a9e67b7586e/implementation-of-extra-security-login-for-sharepoint-2010 
rgds

Comment: Only FBA will not do proper 2-factor AuthN (unless you build something like UAG yourself...)